# Find value in String[] inside List and erase the String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new String[]{"bdc", "house2", "car2"});
data.add(new String[]{"abc", "house", "car"});
```

I have to questions about it:

1. How to find for example, what is the value or second argument if I have `abc`, I want to find the value `house`? (I don't know what is my second argument of course only the first);
2. How to erase all the `String[]` if I have again for example `abc`?

Comment: 1. Iterate through the list, and find the one that contains `"abc"`, then see what the second value is. Something like `for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++) { if(data.get(i)[0].equals("abc")) { System.out.print(data.get(i)[1]; } }`.

Comment: To remove at an index you can do `List.remove(i);`

Comment: If you want to lookup/remove values using a key, a Map would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To access to a given index of an array, use the square brackets `array[index]` knowing that `index` goes from `0` to `array.length - 1`.
2. To remove an element of a `Collection` while iterating over it, you can use `iterator.remove()`.

So your code could look like:

```
// Flag used to know if it has already been found
boolean found = false;
for (Iterator<String[]> it = data.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String[] values = it.next();
    // Check if the first element of the array is "abc"
    if (values.length > 1 && "abc".equals(values[0])) {
        if (found) {
            // Already found so we remove it
            it.remove();
            continue;
        }
        // Not found yet so we simply print it
        System.out.println(values[1]);
        found = true;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
house
```

---

**Response Update:**

As you seem to want to get the index in the list when we get a match, you can simply add a variable `index` that you will increment too in the `for` loop.

```
int index = 0;
for (Iterator<String[]> it = data.iterator(); it.hasNext();index++) {
    ...
    if (values.length > 1 && "abc".equals(values[0])) {
        System.out.printf("abc found at %d%n", index);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc found at 1
house
```

Comment: but "clear" clean all the list? I want to clear or erase the index where is "abc", for example the index 1 or wherever this "abc", thanx

Comment: The output is this:

`house`
`[abc, house, car]`
`[bdc, house2, car2]`

the first line is what I wanted, but when I print again "data" the `String[]` `[abc, house, car]` is there, so I need remove that index where I find the word, in this case, that "abc", thanx for your help

Comment: use Arrays.toString(myArray)

Comment: To clarify, when I find the second argument using the first argument,  in this case `house` using `abc`, is there  way to find what is the index in the `List`?